# xlwings looping through selected cells

Tags: python, excel, selection, xlwings

I am using xlwings to interface with excel. I am attempting to loop through all selected cells.

The issue I am having is it doesn't just loop through the selected cells, it appears to loop through the range in-between as well. Is there a way to loop through just the selected cells with my **selectedCells** object?

I have B2, B5 and B6 selected.
[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Romh6.png)

```
import xlwings as xw

awb = xw.books.active #sets active workbook
selectedCells = awb.app.selection

for value in selectedCells:
    print(value.raw_value)

Output 
CAT
BIRD
PIG

Expected output 
CAT
DOG
HORSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to `split` the address:

```
for address in selectedCells.address.split(','):
    for cell in selectedCells.sheet.range(address):
        print(cell.raw_value)
```

Output:

```
CAT
DOG
HORSE
```

**EDIT**:

Use `.api` and then `.Value`.

```
for cell in selectedCells.api:
    print(cell.Value)
```

Comment: @MaxMusic - see the edit - seems doable with `.api`. Though I bet `.Value` won't work if this is an Excel-on-the-web workbook.